# Remove trailing ? [question mark] from url - empty query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, opencart

I am moving a website to a new Open Cart install and I have set up 301 redirects to keep any SEO value.

I had to use the following trick here - [http://www.itsadam.co.uk/opencart-301-redirect-not-working-seo-fix-*route*/](http://www.itsadam.co.uk/opencart-301-redirect-not-working-seo-fix-_route_/) - to work around an annoying issue with the way Open Cart handles url rewrites. So, I have this sort of thing in my .htaccess file currently:

```
redirect 301 /products-page /products?
```

However, this now leaves my rewritten urls with a trailing ? - an empty query string effectively:

```
http://www.mysite.com/products?
```

Is there a way I can use rewrites to match and ditch any superfluous question marks? (I need to retain any actual query strings).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "trick," and how you wish to retain the query string?

Comment: Please tell us how are you getting your redirection at present?

Comment: I have fixed the broken link and added an example of my current redirect method - the trailing ? is specifically there to fix an issue whereby Open Cart otherwise changes the url to /index.php?_route_=products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same issue in opencart. Rather than follow the link to your solution do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^original-url$ new-url [L,R=301]
```